# Copy a list of files to remote computer while creating parent folders

Tags: command-line, rsync, scp

I have a list of files lying in subdirectories which I have created by calling `find`:

```
for f in $(find . -name "myFile.txt"); do 
    echo "$f" >> filelist.txt;
done
```

The content of `filelist.txt` looks like this:

```
./First/Path/To/File/myFile.txt
./Second/Path/To/File/myFile.txt
./Third/Path/To/File/myFile.txt
...
```

Now I want to copy all these files to a remote computer such that they are placed in the corresponding folders:

```
remoteComputerName:/some/root/directory/First/Path/To/File/myFile.txt
remoteComputerName:/some/root/directory/Second/Path/To/File/myFile.txt
remoteComputerName:/some/root/directory/Third/Path/To/File/myFile.txt
```

However on the remote computer the folder structure `First/Path/To/File/` etc, does not exist yet and also I don't want to copy the entire directories but only the file `myFile.txt` in it.

I know that on a local computer this works using the command

```
while read p; do cp --parents $p /some/root/directory ; done < filelist.txt
```

However for remote computers using `scp` this option `--parents` doesn't work anymore. Also `rsync` doesn't create a parent directory if it's missing.
Does someone know a solution?

Comment: I've deleted my answer, because it wasn't good at all. Namely it would have required authenticating twice for each file, which I'd say it's indeed a no deal. However I've pasted it here for the moment, in case you or someone else want to do something with it: http://paste.ubuntu.com/15538652/. If I find a good way to change it so that authenticating twice is no more necessary I'll undelete my answer (in any case heemayl's answer is most likely the way to go about this).

Comment: Ah, and the notice about the pitfalls when using `for f in $(find [...])`: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `rsync`:

```
rsync -av --files-from=filelist.txt . remote:/some/location/
```

Run this from the directory where you have run `find`, the root of the directories, where the `filelist.txt` currently is.

`--files-from` reads files (newline separated) to be copied from the file `filelist.txt`.

`--files-from` should always use relative path (unlike mentioning directly), although you can be explicit about it:

```
rsync -av --relative --files-from=filelist.txt . remote:/some/location/
```

Comment: This seems to work nicely thank you :). I guess the dot `.` specifies the source directory which is in this case the current directory ?

Comment: @mcExchange Yes and the `filelist.txt` contains files relative to `.`